# Difference between "not being tall" and "being not tall."

Tags: infinitives, subjects

> ___ should not become a serious disadvantage in life and work
>   A. To be not tall  B. Not being tall  C. Being not tall

The above is a test question, to which the answer is B. I kind of doubt it because I think C also works. So I come to seek confirmation.

Do you think the answer should be B and C?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see by ngrams from books.google.com that sentences are started with "Being not" really more rare than "Not being" sentences.

[image: books.google.com Ngram]
So I tried to find sentences from literature started with "Being not" and found one example:

> **Being not much bigger** than the halflings themselves, the human youth could, and did, put up a fight that got him nowhere except beaten with sharp sticks and bound with ropes around his wrists and neck.

In this case "not" have relations with "much" not with "Being".

So I think answer **B** is right answer and **C** is incorrect.

Comment: C is not idiomatic English.